# Sum of the sine of values from $0$ to $\pi/2$ with some distance between angles.

Tags: trigonometry

I want to find the sum

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\pi/(2\delta)}\sin n\delta$$

Where we're summing over all numbers from $0$ to $\pi/2$, with some $\delta$ descriping the distance between them.

For example with $\delta=0.001$, how do I find the value of $$\sin(0) + \sin(0.001) + \sin(0.002) + \dots + \sin(1.570)$$

Comment: Do you mean the integral $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(x)dx$ ? The sum of all possible values just does not exist!

Comment: Closing this was definitely a mistake.  And quite obviously.

Comment: There's an infinite amount of values between $0$ and $\pi/2$, so summing them up simply gives $\infty$. Do you mean what's the sum if we take all numbers with some distance between them, like what's the sum of $\sin(0),\sin(0.001)$ and so on, ignoring the values inbetween? Do you mean something else?

Comment: You should know that the set of values of $x$ is infinite, and there are countable and no-countable sets. Countable set is as the set of integers, and incountable as the interval (0,1). (countable set is to uncountable one as sand is to water). If you want an uncoutable set of $x$ then you want to compute something like the integral mentionned by Winther above, if you want a countable set then it is something like an infinite series which have to be clearly set-up.

Comment: @KristofferRyhl I mean using some distance between the angles.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Then reword your question, and it will probably be reopened.

Comment: I just rejected a proposed edit to the question.  I think we should not try to correct all mathematical errors in questions, but rather save that (in most cases, perhaps) for what we write in answers.  A question may be tacitly asking what the error is, and then the question is lost if the error is corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking your example with $\delta = 0.001$, we have to evaluate 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N}\sin(n \delta)$$
where $N = \text{floor}(\pi/(2\delta)) = 1570$. We can evaluate the sum by recognizing that $\sin(x) = \text{Im}(e^{ix})$, so
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{N}\sin(n \delta) &= \text{Im}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N} e^{i n \delta}\right)\\
&= \text{Im}\left(\frac{1 - e^{i (N+1)\delta}}{1 - e^{i \delta}} \right) \\
&= \text{Im}\left( \frac{e^{i(N+1)\delta/2}}{e^{i\delta/2}}\frac{\sin((N+1)\delta/2)}{\sin(\delta/2)} \right) \\
&= \frac{\sin((N+1)\delta/2)}{\sin(\delta/2)} \text{Im}(e^{iN\delta/2}) \\
&= \frac{\sin((N+1)\delta/2)\sin(N\delta/2)}{\sin(\delta/2)} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\frac{\cos(\delta/2) - \cos((N + 1/2)\delta)}{\sin(\delta/2)}
\end{align}$$
assuming I didn't make any calculation errors. :-)

Note that if $\delta$ is small, then $\cos(\delta/2) \approx 1$, and $\sin(\delta/2) \approx \delta/2$, and $\cos((N+1/2)\delta) \approx \cos(\pi/2) = 0$, so the answer above is approximately
$$\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1 - 0}{\delta/2}\right) = \frac{1}{\delta}$$

Note also how this result relates to the integral $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(x) dx$, which amounts to calculating
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N} \delta \cdot \sin(n \delta)$$
in the limit as $\delta \to 0$. By the approximation above, 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N} \delta \cdot \sin(n \delta) = \delta\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N} \sin(n \delta)\right)\approx \delta \cdot \left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right) = 1$$ 
for small $\delta$, which is consistent with the integral
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x) dx = 1$$
as mentioned in Michael Hardy's answer.

Comment: You might add that this is approximately equal to $\frac{1}{\delta}$ (i.e. very large for small $\delta$).

Comment: @Winther: Good suggestion, I'll edit now.

Comment: Factoring out one half of the exponential is a smart trick! Would this relate to some existing theorem I probably did not aware of? I was calculating this for cosine spacing with a given total length, i.e., $\sum_{n=0}^{N}\cos(n \delta) = \text{Re}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N} e^{i n \delta}\right)=\ell$ where I need to find $\delta$ then.

Answer (score 0):

Before editing, the question seemed to be about the sum
$$
\sum \{ \sin x : 0\le \frac \pi 2 \le x\}.
$$
The value of this sum is $\infty$, by one reasonable definition: All of the numbers are non-negative.  In that situation one can define the sum as the smallest number that can never be exceeded by the sum of finitely many of the numbers in the set.

If you specify $\delta=0.001$, as you did, then you do not include *all* numbers between $0$ and $\pi/2$ since you don't include any between $0$ and $0.001$ nor between $0.001$ and $0.002$, etc.  Then the problem is tractable, as pointed out in another answer.

Another thing the question could mean is: what is the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin x\,dx$?  Imagine a quantity growing $\sin x$ times as fast as $x$ grows, as $x$ grows from $0$ to $\pi/2$.  Then this integral is how much it grows.  It can be shown to be equal to $1$.